# Pointer to element of object representation or pointer to an element of the provided storage?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer

Let's suppose I have the following code:

```
int* p = new (new unsigned char[3*sizeof(int)]) int{};
unsigned char* b = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p);
auto b2 = b + 2*sizeof(int);//it is UB if compilers do not assume that
                            //b is pointer to an unsigned char[3*sizeof(int)]
int* p2 = new (b2) int{};
```

If `b` is not a pointer to the array of `3*sizeof(int)` unsigned char that provides storage for `*p`, then the section [expr.add] of the C++ standard implies that `b+2*sizeof(int)` is undefined behavior (UB). Otherwise if the compiler must assume that `b` is also a pointer to the array of unsigned char that provides storage for `*p` then it is not UB.

So is it specified in the standard that compilers must assume that `b` is a pointer to the `unsigned char[3*sizeof(int)]`that provides storage for `*p`?

Answer (score 1):

According to [expr.static.cast]:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 void” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T”, where T is
>   an object type and cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. If the original
>   pointer value represents the address A of a byte in memory and A does not satisfy the alignment requirement
>   of T, then the resulting pointer value is unspecified. Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an
>   object a, and there is an object b of type T (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible (6.9.2)
>   with a, the result is a pointer to b. Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion.

According to [expr.reinterpret.cast]:

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue v of
>   object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is static_cast(static_cast(v)).

So I will suppose b point to an element of the array of three unsigned char.